# why does it show Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0 after testing my testng.xml on the terminal, not on eclipse?

Tags: java, linux, selenium, terminal, devops

this question is apparently a duplication of another asked but it's not (the title make it look like it's duplicated)
first of all I have a testMethod that I inplemented in eclipse on the file Demo.java:

```
    package com.star.Simulation;

    import org.testng.annotations.Test;//there are many 
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;//imports of the same 
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;//library because it's 
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;//done automatically
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaOptions;

    public class Demo {
    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "/path/to/operadriver");
                OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver(options);
            driver.get("http://validaddress:validport/simulation/index.star");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.findElement(By.id("formConnexion:login")).sendKeys("0100");
            driver.findElement(By.id("formConnexion:password")).sendKeys("star");
            driver.findElement(By.id("formConnexion:j_idt13")).click();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            String aurl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            String eurl = "http://validaddress:validport/simulation/index.star";
            if (aurl.equalsIgnoreCase(eurl))
                System.out.println("failed");
            else
                System.out.println("success");
            driver.quit();
        }
}
```

next I have generated a testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="1" allow-return-values="true">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.star.Simulation.Demo"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

next I have tested both the .java and the .xml many times on eclipse and had the perfect result but when I tried to test the .xml with the terminal using the command : `java -cp "./lib/*:./bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml` I have this result:

```
===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

like you must have seen I am running CentOS7 machine, I have tried using java8 and java11, same results
(my expected result is obviously `Total tests run: 1`)
can you help me? thanks in advance

Comment: give full path and try like this set classpath=C:\Users\Duser\eclipse-workspace\Demo-Project\bin;C:\Users\Duser\eclipse-workspace\Demo-Project\lib\*;
java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Comment: before the command I made a cd to the project root, where the bin and lib exist, anyway I tried giving the full path but it did not work

Comment: where is your library loaded on project path or somewhere else ?

Comment: the library is located in the/project/path/lib, that is where eclipse also has his libraries but like I said, everything works perfect in eclipse but it doesn't do anything on the terminal (with the -cp flag)